# How to print only once inside a while loop in python

Tags: python

I want to print inside a while loop only once. As shown below:

```
 # Starting a while-loop
  while True: 
     # Asking for input(a and b)
     a = int(input('enter a number'))
     b = int(input('enter another number'))
     # If a is bigger than print('bigger than b')
     if a>b:
         print('a is bigger then b')
     # Otherwise...
     else:
         print('b is bigger than a')
     # Start all over again from a = int(input('enter a number'))
```

Now I don't want to entirely stop the loop using `break` or `condition = True`. I just want the loop to start all over again.
If you want any clarifications, feel free to ask

Comment: How many times do you want to take input?

Comment: Could you maybe add pseudo code for your expected output?

Comment: no i want i to start again and again and not look like

`b is bigger than a`
`b is bigger than a`
`b is bigger than a`

Comment: @tjallo ill try

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to say. What do you want as output?

Comment: what is your condition to stop that loop?

Comment: I'm wondering if @snoopstick wants to have the screen cleared?

Comment: If you know the iterations use for loop

Comment: @tanmayjain69 I want it to not  print 'b is bigger than' again and again i want the loop to start all over

Comment: @snoopstick Your code is correct then because it is doing the same thing that you want and if you want to clear the screen you can use import os and os.system('cls')

Comment: So you want to print only during the first run and after that you want an endless loop that asks for a number and another number until the end of time?

Comment: YES @Matthias thank you so much for understanding what I want. But endless loop till the end of time sounds weird...

Comment: Check the answer from @AnsFourtyTwo then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a counter that will input values continuously and print only once.

```
i=1
while True:

     # Asking for input(a and b)
     a = int(input('enter a number'))
     b = int(input('enter another number'))
     if i==1:
        i=i+1
        if a>b:
             print('a is bigger then b')
        else:
             print('b is bigger than a')
     else:
         continue
```

Comment: No need for `continue`. That happens automatically at the end of the loops body. And `if` isn't a function, so `if(i==1):` should be written as `if i == 1:`.

Comment: Oh yess, I guess I'm still stuck with C syntax

Answer (score 3):

To execute some block of code only once within an endless `while` loop, you need to use a flag like in the example below:

```
printed_flag = False
while True:
    a = int(input('enter a number'))
    b = int(input('enter another number'))

    if printed_flag:
        if a>b:
            print('a is bigger then b')
        else:
            print('b is bigger than a')
        printed_flag = False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add in a counter to repeat the loop until the counter stops. What was done below is to set the counter to infinity.

```
i = 0
while i <= float("inf"):
    i += 1
    a = int(input('enter a number'))
    b = int(input('enter another number'))

    if a>b:
        print('a is bigger then b')
    else:
        print('b is bigger than a')
```

Comment: Something you might want to address: The message is wrong if you enter the same number twice.